# Content is in front of header when scroll

Tags: html, css

I have created a header with styles `position:sticky; top:0;`, but when the content is scrolled. The content position is in front of the header not behind it. How to fix it?

In the below picture, the ocean blue box is in front of the blue navbar. It should be behind the navbar.

```
<header style="position: sticky;top: 0;">
    <div class="" data-offset-top="200" style="">
         <div class="navbar navbar-default yamm" role="navigation" id="navbar" style="  top:0; padding:0 20px;ackground-color: #003777">

        </div>
      </div>
 </header>

<div id="content" class="clearfix" style="height:100vh; overflow:auto; ">
    <div style=" height: 100%; background-image: url('https://abcde.png');background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 ">
           <div class="outer" style="margin: 0 auto;width: 30%; background-color: #ECFAFF; font-family:fabio; overflow:hidden;">
              <div style="padding:30px 30px 15px">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

I can solve this issue with `z-index` property. I gave `z-index` property to the wrong element before, so it didn't work as expected.

Another question was: In the image below there is a y-axis scroll. I'm using `height:100vh` expecting the height is equal to screen size. So it's only showing scroll when content is more than screen size. But since the content is not that big. why is there a y-axis scroll?
[image]

Comment: Add `z-index` higher on `header`

Comment: @LaljiTadhani add z-index to 9999 but not works

Comment: Add your HTML & CSS Code here

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I just realize i put z-index in a wrong place before. I got another question there. Why scroll is showing when the content size i still enough ?

Comment: You can check the edit in the answer for your issue

Answer (score 1):

`answer #1`

```
<header style="position: sticky;top: 0; z-index: 1000;">
    ...
</header>
...
```

use `z-index`

`answer #2`

```
.name_of_class{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

set `min-heigth`

**Try This**

Comment: I'm also have another question there. Why it's showing scroll y?

Comment: in `<header>` tag ?

Comment: set  `<header>` set width: 100%; and `<body>` set overflow-y: hidden

Comment: check edited answer

Comment: The content scroll, why the content is showing scroll there?

Comment: I set the content height 100vh. Hoping it's 100% height equals to screen. But since there is header already , total height become 100vh + header, so it's showing scroll . How to set the content height 100% correctly?

Comment: @lauwispremium check my second answer

Comment: added on content   change height from 100vh to 100% and minheight 100%. But not works

Answer (score 1):

You should add z-index property to your header so that is displays above everything.

The default z-index of all elements is 0. If you give z-index to any element above 0 then the content is displayed above any other element and if given z-index is negative then it will be displayed below other elements.

```
<header style="position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 99;">
/*Your header content*/
</header>
/*other Elements*/
```

If you don't give position to your element z-index might not work as you want.

The reason of scrollbar showing up is that: the `height: 100vh` is for the element with `id: content` but you also have the height of `header` element there.

so if you don't want the scrollbar you can give a height of 100vh minus height of header component.

This can be done using `height: calc(100vh - whatever the height of header is);`

Comment: If the height of header is dynamic, How to implement it ?

Comment: do you mean you haven't given any specific height to header ? or you mean the height changes based on viewport height?

Answer (score 0):

** You need to add a z-index to the header so it comes to the top of your content. Or put z-index value -1 to content div this will also work fine **

```
<header style="position: sticky;top: 0;z-index:1000">
  <div class="" data-offset-top="200" style="">
     <div class="navbar navbar-default yamm" role="navigation" id="navbar" style="  top:0; padding:0 20px;ackground-color: #003777">
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex` scroll issue fix

```
body{margin:0;}
.wrapper{
   min-height:100vh;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }
#content{flex:1;background:red;}
```

```css
body{margin:0;}
.wrapper{
   min-height:100vh;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
 }
#content{flex:1;background:red;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<header style="position: sticky;top: 0;">
    <div class="" data-offset-top="200" style="">
         <div class="navbar navbar-default yamm" role="navigation" id="navbar" style="  top:0; padding:0 20px;ackground-color: #003777">
fdgfds
        </div>
      </div>
 </header>

<div id="content" class="clearfix" style="overflow:auto; ">
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height: 100%; background-image: url('https://abcde.png');background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 ">
           <div class="outer" style="margin: 0 auto;width: 30%; background-color: #ECFAFF; font-family:fabio; overflow:hidden;">
              <div style="padding:30px 30px 15px; min-height:200px;">
              dsgdsg
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the first and second answer

```
<div style="height: 100%;"><header style="position: sticky;top: 0; index: 1000;">
    <div class="" data-offset-top="200" style="">
         <div class="navbar navbar-default yamm" role="navigation" id="navbar" style="  top:0; padding:0 20px;ackground-color: #003777">

        </div>
      </div>
 </header>

<div id="content" class="clearfix" style="height:100%; overflow:auto; ">
    <div style=" height: 100%; background-image: url('https://abcde.png');background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 ">
           <div class="outer" style="margin: 0 auto;width: 30%; background-color: #ECFAFF; font-family:fabio; overflow:hidden;">
              <div style="padding:30px 30px 15px">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

create a `<div>` set css `height:100%` and inside `<div>` tag paste other Html code
(replace 100vh to 100%)

**Try This**